# create a DataSet using LinqToExcel:

Tags: linq-to-excel

I am using LinqToExcel in my web application for getting WorksheetNames and columnnames, now i want to show some datas in gridview.Is there any method to create a DataSet using LinqToExcel.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to manually create the DataSet if you use LinqToExcel.

Does the gridview.ls have a DataSource property? If it does, then you can have LinqToExcel retrieve a list of objects from the spreadsheet and set the DataSource to that list.

Comment: manually create DataSet means using other methods like oledb etc ?